# How to decompose a multi qubit Clifford unitary into a sequence of clifford gates

Tags: quantum-circuit, gate-synthesis, pauli-gates, clifford-group

What are the algorithms that allow to decompose any given multi qubit Clifford unitary into elementary Clifford operations (e.g. Pauli+CNOT, with no T gate)?

Comment: This may help https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9503016

Comment: BTW, note that Pauli+CNOT do not create the entire Clifford group, you need also e.g. $\sqrt{Z}$ or $H$ for this.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there is a formal way to decompose a n-qubits Clifford operation with gates from {H,X,Y,Z,CNOT}, but I know a paper that uses Monte Carlo Three Search for this purpose: [Automated Quantum Circuit Design with Nested Monte Carlo Tree Search](https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.00132)

Since it can be seen as a combinatorial problem, deep Reinforcement Learning can be a way to get a decomposition of your unitary operation (the agent begins with an empty circuit and at each step he puts a gate on the circuit until he reaches the target or maximal depth allowed). I have worked on this problem during an internship and it seems quite promising.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one method (the KAK decomposition) that is provably minimal in the number of 2-qubit gates, and it's for 2 qubit unitaries. I've found these 2 papers useful on that topic:

- [paper 1](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0507171)
- See Figure 2: [paper 2](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.01063)

Methods for unitaries of more than 2 qubits are not provably minimal in the number of 2-qubit gates unfortunately. I know this is a partial answer, but I hope you find it useful.

Comment: This method is for general unitaries. It's way more complicated than needed for just Clifford gates. Also it's only for 2 qubit gates but the question is about larger gates.

Answer (score 1):

In a paper by Aaronson and Gottesman, there is a construction that uses $O(n^2/log(n))$ Clifford gates to synthesize any n-qubit Clifford circuit, and it runs in poly(n) time. See the construction in the proof of theorem 8 of https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0406196